# Listening to actions on the email intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android application where I allow users to provide some simple feedback for different services I offer. The way I do this is using the email `intent` pre-filled with the feedback info I want. Now I want to be able to know if the user clicked "send" or the `back button` when the email `intent` opened. This is to mark the feedback as being given for that particular service.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult` in your Activity.

App handling your intent should return results like `Activity.RESULT_OK` and `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.